# Can I 'flip' unbalanced paracol columns for two-sided documents?

Tags: two-column, multicol, paracol

I am producing a two-column publication using `paracol`, which has served me awesomely. This publication is for both digital and print distribution.

For the digital version, it looks like this when you view two pages side-by-side:

[image]

This is fine, because digital publications are mostly read as a single continuous document.

For the print publication, however, I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Much more pleasing to read as a book.

I can obviously do this manually (just reset the columnratio and manually put things before/after the column switch), but is there a way to make paracol 'flip' the columns and their widths automatically? I don't know how to code it, but my idea was, with `twosided`:

- For all odd pages, anything before `\switchcolumn` should be placed on the right instead of left.
- For all odd pages, the size of the left column becomes `1 - \columnratio` so 0.42 would become 0.58, for instance.

Can this be achieved?

---

MWE for the above:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, top = 1.3in, headheight = 0.6in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.42}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2.15em}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\lipsum[1-2]
\switchcolumn
\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (9,9); \end{tikzpicture}

\end{paracol}

\newpage

\begin{paracol}{2}

    \lipsum[1-2]
    \switchcolumn
    \begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (9,9); \end{tikzpicture}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \twosided{c} to swap columns.  See page 17 of manual